# Asp.net Update source page when a new windowed page is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a source page which have a button that opens up a page in a new window

```
protected void btn_AddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string response = "<script>window.open('../Inventory/AddNewItemPage.aspx','_blank');</script>";                
    Response.Write(response);
}
```

And in the new windowed page, after adding the new items and closing that page, the source page's data will not include the the new data added until it is refreshed.

Is there any way of invoking a method in the source page from the windowed page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only using client side script.

If you only want to refresh your page include and call this function

```
function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

You can call the function when window is closing

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it did refresh but the code did not ran, could it be because my data reset code is in the if (!Page.IsPostBack) block

Comment: I used window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location; instead of .reload() and it worked, thanks for the idea!